# Keep file with Chromedriver in chrome://downloads

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automate the download of an XML file with Google Chrome. 
I'm using:

- Google Chrome v73.0.3683.75 (64 bits)
- Chromedriver v73
- Selenium WebDriver v3.14.0
- C#

The problem comes up when a message of harmful file appears:

[image: Harmful file message]

As I'm using Chromedriver, I can not interact with this message, so I tried to accept the download from the chrome://downloads page.

Once I open the chrome://downloads page, I click on the Keep button, but an Alert comes up again to confirm the download.

[image: Confirm download popup in chrome://downloads]

This popup is not a popup Selenium and Chromedriver can Handle with the Dismiss()/Accept()/SendKeys()/... methods. When I try to SwitchTo() it, Chromedriver crashes.

I tried to directly send the keystrokes of {TAB} and {SPACE}/{RIGHT} and {ENTER}, but Chrome seems not to catch them...

The full code is:

```
String currentWindow = this.Drivers[Navegador].CurrentWindowHandle;
String popupHandle = "";

((IJavaScriptExecutor)this.Drivers[Navegador]).ExecuteScript("window.open('about:blank','_blank')");

ReadOnlyCollection<String> tabs = this.Drivers[Navegador].WindowHandles;
foreach (string handle in tabs){
    if (handle != currentWindow){
        popupHandle = handle;
        break;
    }
}
this.Drivers[Navegador].SwitchTo().Window(popupHandle);
this.Drivers[Navegador].Navigate().GoToUrl("chrome://downloads");
String script = "return document.querySelector('body > downloads-manager').shadowRoot.querySelector('#downloadsList > downloads-item').shadowRoot.querySelector('#dangerous > paper-button:nth-child(2)');";
//String script = "return document.querySelector('body > downloads-manager').shadowRoot.querySelector('#downloadsList > downloads-item:nth-child(2)').shadowRoot.querySelector('#url').textContent;";
IWebElement boton = (IWebElement) ((IJavaScriptExecutor) this.Drivers[Navegador]).ExecuteScript(script);
boton.Click();
Thread.Sleep(2000);
SendKeys.Send("{TAB}{SPACE}");
Thread.Sleep(1000);
this.Drivers[Navegador].Close();
this.Drivers[Navegador].SwitchTo().Window(currentWindow);
this.Drivers[Navegador].SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
result = true;
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** 
I tried to launch Chrome with all the flags/options/experimental_options/user_preferences/... possible and it doesn't work. These options/arguments seem to be deprecated in the latest versions of Chrome or Chromedriver.

Comment: OK, i’ll Ask the stupid question: why do you want to keep the chromedriver file in youur Downloads folder?

Comment: I’m sorry @C.Peck, but I don't understand your question. The chromedriver file is not in the downloads folder. By default, I open a default instance of Chrome which has as downloads default folder C:\Users\MyUser\Downloads\

Comment: @Carlos i do have the answer for this but sorry i am a java person, so would the answer in java help you ?

Comment: Hi @SameerArora! Yes, please. Tell me the Java solution so I can understand it and make something with C#. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Carlos i have added an answer, so basically you just need to add some capabilities while initiating your chromedriver to solve your problem. Do let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: Hi @SameerArora! I didn't have the time to test it. Hope tomorrow I'll have it... By the way, I think DesiredCapabilties is deprecated with the last version of Chromedriver... I'll let you know the result ;) Thanks for your interest

Answer (score 0):

As discussed with OP, answering the question in Java.

Encountered the same problem few months back, so this is how it worked for me, might work for you as well.

```
Map<String, Object> chromePreferences = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
// Below preferences will disable popup dialog while downloading the file
chromePreferences.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePreferences.put("download.prompt_for_download", "false");

// Set the customised path for downloading the file, if required
chromePreferences.put("download.default_directory", "path");

ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePreferences);

DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);

//Now initiate ChromeDriver with the capabilities set above and continue with your automation
ChromeDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this issue, and due to the deprecation of some of the methods in the ChromeDriver, the above solution didn't work.

After a lot of research I decided to switch to IE and explore an alternate option with the inspiration from this article - https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3169/downloading-a-file-in-internet-explorer-through-selenium/3520 I came up with this solution in JAVA.

It is not as 'clean' but it worked for me.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws NoAlertPresentException,InterruptedException  {                                  
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\selenium-java-3.141.59\\IEDriverServer.exe");

    String url ="myfileurl";

    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.get(url);

    try {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    //press alt+s key to save       
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    }
     catch (AWTException e) {

     e.printStackTrace();
     }

    driver.close();

}
```